# How to escape a double quote in varnish vcl

Tags: varnish, vcl, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

In vcl_recv I'm trying to send a 403 to requests that contain the following characters in the url: ",',<,>,(, and )

```
if(req.url ~ "[\'\<\>()].*\.html" ) {
  return (synth(403, "Forbidden"));
}
```

everything works except the double quote "
I tried regex like:

```
"[\"\'\<\>()].*\.html"
"[\\"\'\<\>()].*\.html"
"[%22\'\<\>()].*\.html"
"[x22\'\<\>()].*\.html"
```

All of them do not compile with "varnishd -C -f default.vcl"
I'm currently on varnish-4.1.1
Does anyone know how to escape the " correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```cpp
if (req.url ~ "[\x27<>()\x22]") {
    return (synth(403, "Forbidden"));
}
```

[Regex test](https://regex101.com/r/Cq3r71/2)

Comment: perhaps we want to allow those chars in the query string `"^/[^\?]*[\x27<>()\x22]"`

Answer (score 2):

`%22` will give you a double quote within your quoted string in Varnish VCL

Comment: Take into account that Fastly VCL has many custom extensions. Percent-escaping is one of those extensions, see https://www.fastly.com/blog/unicode-in-vcl